# md-autocomplete - remove selected items in suggestion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

Im trying to remove an `md-item` in suggestion when the user selected an item and is marked as favorite. To clarify the question here is the structure below.

Supposing that we have this structure of `states`.

```
function loadAll() {

      var allStates = [
          {
             display : Alabama,
             value : alabama,
             is_favorite : false
          },
          {
             display : Alaska,
             value : alaska,
             is_favorite : false
          },
          {
             display : California,
             value : california,
             is_favorite : false
          },
          {
             display : Colorado,
             value : colorado,
             is_favorite : false
          },
          {
             display : Florida,
             value : florida,
             is_favorite : false
          },
          {
             display : Georgia,
             value : georgia,
             is_favorite : false
          },
      ];

      return allStates;
}
```

This is what i did for marking the state as favorite when the user selected the object i put it on the function `md-selected-item-change`.

```
function selectedItemChange(object) {
    if (object) {
        object.is_favorite = true;
    }
}
```

Now it is possible to alter the `createFilterFor()` to exclude from the results the states which has `is_favorite == true` after selecting a particular state?

```
function createFilterFor(query) {
  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

  return function filterFn(state) {
    return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
  };

}
```

This is what ive'd tried so far but it doesn't render the correct result.

```
return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0 && state.is_favorite == false);
```

> UPDATE

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/ZLYLZG?editors=1000)

Comment: Please refer this link i think you might get help : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Comment: hello i cannot find any example from that demo

Comment: Can you please show us your full running code in snippet

Comment: @AshishPatel hi there sorry for not responding as soon as possible, I updated my question with a working codepen.

Comment: so you want to exclude the favorites from the `dropdown`?

Comment: @Yaser yes exactly you can take a look at the working codepen

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab check the answer, already tested in your code pen

Comment: @Yaser im testing please give me a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple fix for this:

```
md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)| filter:{ is_favorite:false }"
```

All you have to do is to put the filter in the source for your control.

Please check the code pen : http://codepen.io/ash972/pen/ZLYNPM

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution

Comment: Happy to help mate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this:

```
function filterFavotites(item) {
  return !item.is_favorite;
}
```

And call it in `querySearch` before returning results:

```
function querySearch (query) {
  var results = query ? vm.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : vm.states,
      deferred;

  results = results.filter(filterFavotites);

  return results;
}
```

Comment: this works well too but Ash has a simple solution. Thanks for the answer!